# PUG - Pass variable to include js file

Tags: express, pug

I have a function that passes a variable 'message' to my pug file. Which works fine within the pug file but I need it to work inside a JS file that I am including in the pug file.

I am including a js file in my pug file like so:

```
include test.js
```

My JS file contains some code with #{message} variable which is passed into my pug file through a function.

```
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "#{message}";
```

Because I am including this JS file through include, it basically shows it as plain text without  tags. Which is exactly what I want. However, I need to insert some custom variables into the JS as its being displayed as a plain text file.

Comment: What output are you getting now?

Comment: Exactly what is in the JS file without the variable being converted to final value.

Comment: @RajaAbbas were you able to find a workaround for this? I am having the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

```
script
  | var nextPageToken = '#{nextPageToken}'
  include dynamicLoad.js
```

Supposing you have the token as string in your template variables, it will pass it to JS.

Please note than `include` in script will dump the JS code, it's not optimized, to load it in a parallel request and benefit the cache browser, use:

```
script
  | var nextPageToken = '#{nextPageToken}'
script(src="dynamicLoad.js ")
```